# Error message appear in a old running flash application during AMFPHP call

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, amfphp, zend-amf

My app was working fine until today. The probleme is that each request to amfphp return an error message like :

```
Client.Error.Message Send
Fail to send
```

In fact, this message is the `fault` function I put in the caller.

```
<s:CallResponder id="tracefilm"/>
    <trace:Trace id="traceFilm" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" result="traceMaked(event)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

Because I don't know how to find where the problem is... I'll try to view what happens thanks to **firebug** plugin of FF during execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. I've just fixed this issue in a old streaming app (100% flash).

If you encountered the problem in a old app, you propably don't have the **crossdomain.xml** file in the root directory of the web server. See [Adobe explanation](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Starting_with_AMFPHP-11947.html) for more details.

I found the solution thanks to **firebug**. In fact, during Flash loading, the browser tried to access to a file called `crossdomain.xml`. Of course, the server response was 404 for my part...

You just have to create `crossdomain.xml` in the server, and to add this piece of code inside :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Now your application, like mine will works again.

Comment: Great, you should validate your own answer.

Comment: Yes, but I have to wait for tomorrow to be able to... ^^